# Cómo generar un diccionario de datos en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

A partir de una base de datos mysql creada en phpmyadmin, el objetivo es obtener el diccionario de datos de esa DataBase

Answer (score 3):

Espero te sirva esta explicación.
Desde el phpMyAdmin, seleccionas la base de datos a la cual le vas a generar el diccionario de datos.
En la parte inferior hay un link para generarlo en vista de impresión.
Te anexo una captura de pantalla.
Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Te diría de usar el exportar de phpmyadmin.

[image: exortar]

**Opción 1**

Lo más rápido, usar los formatos propios de phpmyadmin.

[image: formatos rápidos]

**Opción 2**

Usar la opción de personalizado y en salida pones ver salida como texto. Una vez tengas eso lo puedes sacar al formato que quieras.

[image: personalizado]